Auto load task pane in a newly created Word document from existing word document in a Word add in blazor project?
I have created a new Word document from existing word document in a Word addin Blazor project. I want to add content in a new Word document and also load the task pane in a new word document similar to  existing Word task pane. I have written a code but it does not display the content in a new document, it displays in existing word context and the task pane is also not auto loaded in a new word document. Basically I want to create a word document similar to an existing word document.
export async function createNewDocument() {
    try {
        // Create and open the new document
        let newDocUrl;
        await Word.run(async (context) => {
            const newDoc = context.application.createDocument();
            newDoc.open();

            // Sync to ensure the new document is opened
            await context.sync();

            // Get the URL of the new document (if possible, or use another method)
            newDocUrl = Office.context.document.url; // This helps confirm we're dealing with the new doc
        });

        // Adding a short delay to ensure the new document is fully initialized
        await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));

        // Use another `Word.run` block to interact with the new document explicitly
        await Word.run(async (newContext) => {
            // Ensure the context is correctly tied to the newly opened document
            if (Office.context.document.url === newDocUrl) {
                const newDocument = newContext.document;

                // Insert content into the new document
                newDocument.body.insertText(
                    "This is the new content for the new document.",
                    Word.InsertLocation.end
                );

                // Sync after content insertion
                await newContext.sync();

                // Set the task pane to auto-show with the new document
                Office.context.document.settings.set(
                    'Office.AutoShowTaskpaneWithDocument',
                    true
                );

                // Save the settings asynchronously
                await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    Office.context.document.settings.saveAsync((result) => {
                        if (result.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
                            resolve();
                        } else {
                            reject(result.error);
                        }
                    });
                });

                // Show the task pane explicitly in the new document
                Office.addin.showAsTaskpane();

                // Sync to confirm task pane is shown
                await newContext.sync();
            } else {
                throw new Error("Failed to switch to the new document context.");
            }
        });

    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error creating or modifying the new document: ", error);

        // Detailed error logging
        if (error instanceof OfficeExtension.Error) {
            console.error("Debug info: ", JSON.stringify(error.debugInfo));
        }

        throw error; // Re-throw to handle in the calling function
    }
}

I have successfully created a new word document from existing word document. But I cannot add the content in a new Word document and auto load the task pane as it is similar to existing word task pane. I want to auto load the sideloader in Word. My condition is if the existing document is already saved and it already contains the content I need to create a new document and insert my content or data in a new word document and also load the taskpane(sideloader) same as existing word document? my c# code is below
private async Task<string> EditDocument()
{
    try
    {
              isDocumentSaved = await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<bool>("wordInterop.checkIfDocumentIsSaved");
        Console.WriteLine("status of saved docuemnt"+ isDocumentSaved);
  if (isDocumentSaved == true)
  {
      try
      {
          // Create a new document and ensure all operations are in its context
           await JSModule.InvokeVoidAsync("createNewDocument");     

        
          return "New document created and operations performed.";

      }
catch (Exception ex)
        {
    Console.WriteLine($"Error: {ex.Message}");
                throw new Exception("Error in processing new document: " + ex.Message);
            }

        }

  else
  {
 //perform ooperation in existing word document 
}
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception("message:-"+ ex.Message);
    }

}

